# mysqlのホスト名と、ユーザ名

Tags: mysql

現在接続しているユーザーを確認したところ、下記のような結果になったのですが、これはホスト名が「localhost」、ユーザ名が「root」であるということですか？

```
mysql> select user(), current_user();
+----------------+----------------+
| user()         | current_user() |
+----------------+----------------+
| root@localhost | root@localhost |
+----------------+----------------+
```

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/gex7kifmhgiz2x) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Answer (score 0):

引用ですが、下記のものらしいです。

> user() 関数は接続時に指定したユーザー名とホストを返します。 current_user() 関数は実際に認証されたユーザー名とホストを返します。通常この二つは同じ結果を返しますが、接続時に指定したユーザー名ではないユーザーとして認証がされてしまうケースがあるようです(匿名ユーザーがらみでそうなるようです)。
> https://www.javadrive.jp/mysql/user/index11.html